# Customizing and Developing the plugins and pages In SONAR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sonarqube

I started working on SONAR, I have been analyzing the projects and thats going fine. Two questions has raised

1. If I want to customize the SONAR pages or adding new customized plugins to it, Do I need to have knowledge on RUBY.
2. Can I get SONAR src distribution,so that I can put it in my say Eclipse workspace and modify and add plugins by my own ?

   Need your suggestions,and knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sonar plugins are mainly developed in Java (metric computation, code parsing, resource creation, ...), but if you want to extend Sonar UI, then yes you need Ruby on Rails knowledge.
- You can find Sonar source on GitHub: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar.
- You can also find the sources of lots of Sonar Plugins on the plugins forge's SVN repository: https://svn.codehaus.org/sonar-plugins/trunk/
- And finally, visit the documentation on how to write plugins for Sonar: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Developing+Plugins